# Any Riak Yokozuna custom erlang term extractor available?

Tags: solr, erlang, riak, extractor, riak-search

My basic requirement is proplist actually and I guess I can write a custom extractor for application/erlangproplist.

Just out of curiosity, as Riak is written in Erlang, is there any Erlang term extractor already available out there?

It's going to be very complex extractor I suppose since Erlang term can be in many forms like tuple, proplist etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such extractor embedded in Riak. You can see all available extractors [here](https://github.com/basho/yokozuna/blob/2.0/src/yz_extractor.erl#L31). You will have to build your own. Chances are it would resemble [yz_json_extractor](https://github.com/basho/yokozuna/blob/2.0/src/yz_json_extractor.erl) a great deal.

If you need an extractor for a specific proplist format with some custom extraction logic you can find my old attempt here (gist.github.com/Vorticity-Flux/e0b52cb678ef4f997e06).